# How to make a <td> element look like a nested <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table where I need the last td in the row to look like a nested row.

I can't make it a new row, but I want everything in that `<td> </td>` be nested under that row.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/5b223r32/1/) . You can click the icon to see a new row appear. But I can't use a new row, it needs to be in the same DOM row. I want the last column to move down to look like a new row instead. It doesn't have to align, just get to a new row.

Is there css that will make that happen?

Can I use jquery/js to change the css to make that happen?

Comment: why downvote without any comments?

Comment: *I want everything in that be nested under that row* .... Please clarify your question and add your actual relevant code and expected output

Comment: You could try css display:table-row and each element within with css display:table-cell. <td style="display:table;"><div style="display:table-row"><div style="display:table-cell"></div></div></td>

Comment: Just use a nested table within your `<td>`

Comment: updated with fiddle. @BlueEyedBehemoth yes I did that. please see fiddle. But how do I get the `<td>` to go down a row?

Comment: Why you can't make it a new row? any particular reason ?

Comment: @DaniP I am using datatables to format the table and it filters out my childrows. I am trying to get it into a `td` of that row so I can use the datatables childrows api to format it into a new row. Ajax call didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use colspan for the tr and give it the  number of columns you  have...then you will only need one td

Answer (score 1):

You could hide some cells and then use `colspan` to span the remaining columns.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
    <td>2.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hide">3.1</td>
    <td class="hide">3.2</td>
    <td class="hide">3.3</td>
    <td colspan=4>3.4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table {width:100%;color:white}
td {background:blue}
tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {background:green;}
.hide {display: none;}
```

Comment: This code was written by a dog.  That's how you know it's good.